# error en @cucumberOption

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, cucumber

buen dia tengo este error no me reconoce @cucumberOption tengo la librería instalada estoy trabajando con java en el edito IJalguien que me pueda ayudar gracias

```
package co.com.choucair.certification.proyectobase.runners;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.core.snippets.SnippetType;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/test/resources/features/academyChoucair.feature",
        tags="@tag1",
        glue="co.com.choucair.certificacion.proyectobase.stepdefinitions",
        snippets=SnippetType.CAMELCASE)



public class RunnerTags {
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
alguien me podria ayudar  ???

Comment: Por favor se más específico e indica el error que aparece en tu consola.

Comment: ya especifique el error llevo días enfrascado en esto pudiera ofrecer recompensas lo haría ayuda :(

Comment: Podrias pasar la lista de dependencias que tienes en el proyecto? o bueno, las relacionas a cucumber, asi nos aseguramos de que en realidad este bien importada. @sinjrnohaysr

Answer (score 1):

Estimado su problema es por que importo mal la libreria de cucumber y el cucumberoption en import esta en rojo, por que no encuentra su libreria relacionada que son las siguientes: Estas son para la version de cucumber 7

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Siempre y cuando use junit para ejecutar su runner y selenium. Estoy notando que usa api.cucumber. En ese caso recomiendo usar y las librerias que coloque mas arriba.

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

Saludos.